PCIe card not recognized
Freshly arrived on Ubuntu OS I really enjoy it!
However, I recently bought a pcie card -> https://www.ebay.com/itm/275880887119?_trksid=p4375194.c101800.m5481
I have the last version of Ubuntu, last bios firmware.. and seems that the card is not detectable by my Asus B450-f.
Is this kind of PCI-E card compatible with Ubuntu?


From the ebay listing it isn't a PCIe card with any endpoint, but a PCI-E X16 to 4 Ports SFF-8643 U.2 NVME Expansion. Are are any NMEs devices connected to the card? Also, has the BIOS on the Asus B450-f been set to enable bifurcation on the PCIe slot to which the card has been fitted, as looks necessary to be able to use more than one NVMe device.

Thanks for your reply. I connected a sata ssd and I would like to connect 16 of them (4 by connector). I read on some website that b450 does not support bifurcation. I was totally unaware of this requirement.
